# open remote desktop connection in tkinter tab (PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to open a Remote desktop connection by a click of button. Each button would open a remote desktop connection to a new PC.
I have a HOME tab in which i have two button '1' and '2'
i want to click on button '1' and open the remote desktop for system_1 in a new tab
similarly if i click on button '2', i should open a new tab and show the remote desktop connection of system_2 in this tab.

Currently with the code that i have written, it opens the remote desktop connection on the click of button but not in tkinter tab. it opens as the usual mstsc opens.

Could some one help to link the remote desktop to the tkinter tab.

Currently i am using a rdp file which has the saved username and password. Could some please also suggest some other good way to open remote desktop connection in Python where i dont have to provide the username and password all the time.

Thanks for your help.

Here is my code

```
SETUPS = {'system_1': ['1', 'RDP1'],
      'System_2': ['2', 'RDP2'], }

main_frame = Tk()

tab_handler = ttk.Notebook(main_frame)

# this creates the TKINTER Home tab
def home_tab():
    h_tab = ttk.Frame(tab_handler)
    tab_handler.add(h_tab, text='HOME')

    tab_handler.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5)

    for idx,setup_name in enumerate(SETUPS.keys()):
        setup_button = Button(h_tab, name=f'{setup_name.lower()}_button', text=f'{SETUPS[setup_name][0]}', height=5, width=5,
                              command=lambda name=setup_name.lower(): open_new_setup(system_name=name))
        setup_button.grid(row=0, column=0+idx, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)

# this function helps to open the tab on click of button
def open_new_setup(system_name: str):
    setup_tab_name = ttk.Frame(tab_handler, name=system_name)
    tab_handler.add(setup_tab_name, text=system_name.upper())

    connect_remote_desktop(remote_desktop_to_pc=SETUPS[system_name][1])
    # select the tab which is opened
    tab_handler.select(setup_tab_name)
    tab_handler.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5)

def connect_remote_desktop(remote_desktop_to_pc: str):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["mstsc", remote_desktop_to_pc.lower()+'.rdp'])

home_tab()

# always open the app in full screen mode
main_frame.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
main_frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: some ppl did implement the protocol in python for PyQT4 [rdpy](https://github.com/citronneur/rdpy), and it's licensed under GPL3, so you can fork it and port it to tkinter, but this will be over a month's work, and you'll have to retain the GPL3 license.

Comment: It's unspecific. Do a preliminary research. See [ask]. Anyway you can't embed the ```mstsc``` client into your application window. Your best bet will be to create a C extension which implements a RDP client with FreeRDP.